# Mathjax show formula expression on web edited by ckeditor

Tags: mathjax

I add Mathjax to my ckeditor and editor some formula expression, but I can only show these formula expression code when I show these formula expression on another place.

This is what I edit on my ckeditor:
[image]

This is what it show on my web:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use mathjax js in your web. it converts tex to formula view